# JBoss 7.1.3 log4j Socketappender isn't outputting classname and methodname

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jboss7.x, logstash

We're trying to integrate logstash into our systems and therefore we're using a Socketappender as a custom-handler in JBoss 7.1.3 as follows:

```
   <custom-handler name="LOGSTASH" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender" module="org.apache.log4j">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %X{user} %X{app} [%C:%M:%L] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <properties>
                <property name="Port" value="56445"/>
                <property name="RemoteHost" value="172.31.52.12"/>
            </properties>
        </custom-handler>
```

The output is reaching the LOGSTASH-Server , but is missing some information. Specifically the classname and the methodname. They are outputted to the JBoss logfile and the console, but the Socketappender just removes them.

The json looks like this:

```
"_index": "logstash-2014.11.20",
"_type": "log4j",
"_id": "eBE6Eg1GS1--zNiaP63Bgg",
"_score": null,
"_source": {
"message": "JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final \"Arges\" wurde gestartet in 39313ms - 4060 von 4230 Diensten gestartet (169 Services sind Passiv oder werden bei Bedarf geladen)",
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2014-11-20T08:45:11.367Z",
"type": "log4j",
"host": "172.31.90.10:34497",
"path": "org.jboss.as",
"priority": "INFO",
"logger_name": "org.jboss.as",
"thread": "Controller Boot Thread",
"class": "?",
"file": "?:?",
"method": "?",
"NDC": "",
"stack_trace": ""
```

The console-output on the server looks like this:

```
09:45:11,070 INFO    [org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapListener:done:157] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" wurde gestartet in 39313ms - 4060 von 4230 Diensten gestartet (169 Services sind Passiv oder werden bei Bedarf geladen)
```

Any help would be apprechiated.

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Add the next parameter to the appender:

```xml
<property name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
```

> The **LocationInfo** option takes a boolean value. If true, the
>   information sent to the remote host will include location information.
>   By default no location information is sent to the server.

See also:

- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.html
- https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html

Comment: First of all thank you for the response. It didn't solve the Problem though. The Information is still missing.

Comment: @MartinIbl I made a mistake, the property must be set  `<property name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>` no `<param name="LocationInfo" value="true" />`

Comment: @MartinIbl Check output the appender, you can use http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i'm still not getting any of the LocationInfo. I was using property instead of param from the beginnning, as it is the convention for a custom handler. When looking at the logs in chainsaw, i'm also getting no LocationInfo.

Comment: @MartinIbl Do you have configured other appender?

Comment: We have a console-handler and a periodic-rotating-file-handler. Both are outputting the class and method with line-number just fine.